# android: dynamically adding images into listview

Tags: android, listview

I have two listviews, one is simple and the other is custom (it has a picture, a text and a button). I want to add images into simple listview dynamically.How? 
when the button in custom listview is clicked.

I would Appreciate your answer. 
Thank You.

Comment: did you implement you list view, your activity and your list adapter ?

Comment: Assuming that your simple list view has an adapter with an array of items (which it must) just add the images to the array the adapter is using and invalidate the adapter data when you press the button

Comment: @Yama Raahi, what you did so far ?

Comment: So far, I have Two listviews. one is simple and the other is custom listview with a layout. I worked on it, now when I Click on the listitem(not the button) which is in custom listview, a text will be added into simple listview.
I have two problems: 
1: the  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working in customAdapter class.(I want the text be added when the button in custom listview is clicked)
 
2: When I tried adding images dynamically into simple listview, Some integer numbers got added, not the image itself. (I want to add images when the button in custom listview is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this.**

Create a class by extending the BaseAdapter.

In the adapter, keep a variable called itemsToDisplay.

Return this variable in getCount().

Return your custom views in getView().

Wherever you display the list, add a button at the bottom that says: Load More Images or whatever.

Clicking the button will increment the itemsToDisplay by some value.

Call the notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter to display more images after the change in itemsToDisplay.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
but I have two listviews. and I want to add images in one listview through click of a button in another listview.